# "Replace" or "Substitute" - Taking someone's job position and giving that to someone else

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

As you know the word "replace" can be used in the sense of taking someone else's job position.

I'm going to say:

They removed me from my job, position and gave my position to someone else. (referring to nepotism or just having personal grudge against me.)

Please have a look on the following sentences and let me know if I can use "substitute" instead of replace  without any specific change in meaning?

> 1. They **replaced** me with that girl.
> 2. They **substituted** that girl for me.

If no, then please tell me why?

Comment: This is very similar to the recent question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/225199/replace-versus-substitute-sentence-structure/225202#225202 by the same asker. Answers there may be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A substitution is usually temporary, while a replacement is more permanent. In some contexts they can be the same, but when talking about people they are probably different.

If they replaced you, they got rid of you and hired someone else.

If they substituted someone else for you it seems like you are still their first choice, but someone else had to come in for a while. This could happen if you are on vacation, or out sick.

In industries where 'substitutes' are commonly recognized (teaching and sports come to mind) the difference is very stark.

[Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216188/replace-vs-substitute) is another question on the subject.

Comment: Well, just let me ask you one to the point question @Sarah. Based on what you mentioned, the verb "substitute" encapsulates "temporary". Then I was wondering if for instance in the following sentence, the adjective "temporary" is superfluous or that's okay? (**Example:** I'm just a **temporary** substitute for the receptionist.)?

Comment: @A-friend yes temporary is unnecessary in the sentence, but it doesn't feel overly redundant. I think your sentence is fine with or without it.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely *can* use *substitute* here, but given your intended meaning I would strongly prefer *replaced*.

The main reason for this is that *substitute* implies strong similarity between two things. Using that word here give the impression, if subtly, that you and *that girl* are roughly interchangeable-- there isn't much difference in which of you holds the job, and *they* were aware of that when they made the decision.

*Replaced* gives a stronger impression that you were removed (for whatever reason), and then afterwards *that girl* was installed in the position.