# "Replace" versus "Substitute" - Sentence structure

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I have a question about the words order and their effect on the meaning of a sentence when it comes to use the verbs "replace" and "substitute"!

As far as I know, "to replace someone / something **with** someone / something else" means "to substitute someone / something **for** someone / something else".

Additionally, as far as I am concerned, if you are **replacing A with B**, then you are **substituting B for A.**

But problem is that if changing the words' places in each structure makes any difference in meaning?

For instance, does it make any difference if I say:

- > 1. Yesterday, I had a terrible quarrel with the company's directing manager and they are going to **replace me with Sam** Or **substitute Sam for me**.
- > 2. Yesterday, I had a terrible quarrel with the company's directing manager and they are going to **replace Sam with me** Or **substitute me for Sam**.

Let me simplify it! The inly thing that is important in the meaning of the two is that:

(Replace X with Y **=** Substitute Y for X)

But I need to know if replacing X and Y has a specific connotation in English? For example, in:

- > 1.a. They  are going to replace Sam with me. 
  >   1.b. They  are going to substitute me for Sam.

..........................

- > 2.a. They  are going to replace me with Sam. 
  >   2.b. They  are going to substitute Sam for me.

I was wondering which set implies that I was the first employee and Sam is taking my place?

Also which set implies that I as a new employee am taking Sam's place?

I hope I could make myself understood.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a native English speaker from the western United States.

To begin, think of those two words in this way:

**Replace** means (a) to take something out and put in *the very same thing* or (b) to take something out and put in something *permanently.* For example, you replace the wheel on your car with a wheel of the same make, size, design, etc. Perhaps there are minor differences (you bought a tire from a different manufacturer), but the item taken away and the item put back are substantially identical and the replacement was permanent.

**Substitute** means to take something out and put in *something that's adequate, perhaps even appropriate, but not the very same thing* and it often (but not always) suggests a *temporary* condition. For example, you substitute the wheel on your car with the itty-bitty spare tire sold with most modern cars. Driving on the spare for ten seconds will prove it's not "substantially identical" (in fact, driving on those tiny tires is often a pain in the neck). Further, it's meant to be temporary until you can get the original tire fixed (although I've seen people drive permanently on those little tires.  I wouldn't recommend that.) However, temporary is not a requirement for using the word "substitute." In the world of replacement parts for cars, a 3rd-party part often substitutes for the OEM (original equipment manufacturer) part on a permanent basis.

You should not be surprised that native English speakers use the two words interchangeably, but they should not. Yes, both words mean something was taken away and another thing was put in its place. The difference between the words is they give you context as to what was put in its place and, possibly, why.

Now that we've established context, let's look at your examples.

(1a) means you're no longer involved. Sam is permanently taking your place. It might mean you've been fired, or that you're no longer working on a project — but it suggests a permanent decision.

(1b) means you're temporarily relieved of duty. Perhaps your boss thinks Sam would do a better job presenting something to a specific customer, so for that one meeting he's substituting for you, the person who would normally make that presentation. You would expect to continue making that presentation to other customers.

Are these statements equivalent? No, but you will often hear English speakers use both words to mean (1b) but you will rarely (very rarely) hear both words used for (1a) as I've defined the context.

Example #2 is more likely to be equivalent because you have provided additional context ("while I'm away...") to help the reader understand what is happening. You've established that the "take away and put in place" action is *temporary.* Thus, the two words could be used interchangeably (but it would be more correct to use 2a).

Comment: Thank you JBH; I'm almost close to my needed information. Then I wonder if I can substitute "He has resigned and he's being replaced by me" for "...I'm being substituted for him" or "I'm replacing him." Does the bold sentences sound natural and idiomatic to you? If no, then what is wrong with them and why? Please kindly enlighten me.

Comment: "He hs resigned and he's being replaced by me" would imply a permanent replacement and would be synonymous with "I'm replacing him." However, "I'm substituting for him" implies a temporary replacement. Frankly, your English is excellent. All of your examples would draw no undue attention from a native.

Comment: That's really kind of you @JBH. Just for the conclusion, lets check three other cases with you. Just let me know whether you confirm my take on your statements.

Comment: According to what you mentioned and my take, we can say: [1] While I'm away on vacation, **"another teacher will substitute for me**" or "**I'll be replaced by another teacher**" or "**another teacher will replace me**". Also [2] In modern life, "**email has replaced traditional letters**" or  "**traditional letters have been replaced by email**" or "**email has substituted for traditional letters**". And finally, [3] "**The internet cannot replace human interaction**" or "**Human interaction cannot be replaced by the internet**" or "**The internet cannot substitute for human interaction**"

Comment: [1] correct. [2c] would be understood by English speakers in my area, but it's not the best choice as most people have made a permanent transition to email. Otherwise, [2] is good. [3] is understandable, but more complex because human interaction and the Internet are are not entirely equivalent. Substitution/replacement in this context has more to do with metaphor and philosophy than the practical uses of either word. In many cases, these statements are meant to subjectively demean the value of the Internet by suggesting the replacement was permanent with a substandard substitute.

Comment: However, all versions of [3] would be (and probably have been) used by article writers when discussing diminished human interaction with the motivation of blaming the Internet or Social Media. All three examples would be reasonably understood, but which one is preferred would depend on the motivation for writing the statement (IMO).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that "**replacing A with B**" and "**substituting B for A**" have essentially the same meaning. In both cases A was there first, A was removed, and B was put in its place. If we said "**replacing B with A**" then B was there first.

When dealing with people, particularly in an employment context, "substitute" tends to suggest a temporary change, while "replace" tends to indicate a permanent change.

> - Jane is having an operation, and will be out for two months, so Bill will substitute for her.
> - Martha got a poor review and has left the company, so she will be replaced by Fred.

The difference is subtle, but significant. However, it cannot be relied on -- "substitute" can be used for a permanent change, and "replace" for a temporary change, althoguh this is unusual in my experience.

Now let's look at the examples from the question:

> - 1A. Yesterday, I had a terrible quarrel with the company's directing manager and they are going to replace me with Sam.
> - 1B. Yesterday, I had a terrible quarrel with the company's directing manager and they are going to substitute Sam for me.

These are both grammatical, and carry much the same meaning, aside from the nuance I mentioned above, which would favor 1A over 1B.

> - 2A. Yesterday, I had a terrible quarrel with the company's directing manager and they are going to replace Sam with me.
> - 2B. Yesterday, I had a terrible quarrel with the company's directing manager and they are going to substitute me for Sam.

2A and 2B also have very similar meanings to each other, but quite different from (indeed opposite to) 1A and 1B.  However 2a/2B seem internally inconsistent. They say that Sam is going out and "me" is going in, but that doesn't seem consistent with "I had a terrible quarrel". I suppose these might be possible if Sam's position was of lower rank or status, and "replace Sam with me" means a demotion fro the speaker. They would make better sense if they said "**Sam** had a terrible quarrel", then the two clauses would be consistent.

Comment: Thank you @David Siegel, just let me ask another question to make sure. Please imagine in a soccer match an old player runs out of breath and energy  during the play and cannot run anymore. Which choice would be correct? **a.** The younger player was substituted for him. **b** The old player was substituted for a younger younger player. --- To me, they both work and mean the same.

Comment: Also, you mentioned: "Martha got a poor review and has left the company, so she will be replaced **by** Fred.", while as far as I know, someone can only be "replaced **with** someone else and whereas someone else can replace A **with** B, hence, A can be replaced **with** B, **by C**. Please kindly let me know about it too.

Comment: @ A-friend It is perhaps more common to say "Replace A with B" but it is perfectly normal to say "A will be replaced by B". The meaning is the same. This is not the same use of "by" as a use indicating an agent, as in "The action was performed by C"

Comment: Therefore, @David Siegel if I'm not mistaken, I can say either: "Replace A **with** B" or "Replace A **by** B" - Also, "A will be replaced **with** B" or "A will be replaced **by** B". Right?

Comment: @A-friend Yes that is all absolutely correct.

Comment: Also @David Siegel I see people sometimes use "by" instead of "for" in: "substitute X **for** Y" and say: "substitute X **by** Y". Does the same go there too?

Comment: @A-friend  I would not use or advise the use of "substitute X by Y, but I am not prepared to say that it is incorrect. If it is used, i would understand it to mean the same as  "substitute X for Y", and so you will understand what others mean if they use that form.